# Convert Hex to Dec in bash

Tags: bash, hash, decimal, zsh

I want to convert Hex to decimal.
I'm using Zsh, but even bash command is ok

For now I try with

```
echo $((0x0000000000000000003218a50000000000000000000000000000000000000000))
```

but the result is truncated

```
zsh: number truncated after 34 digits: 0000000000000000003218a50000000000000000000000000000000000000000
3609816520756035584
```

I want the same result that I retrieve from this [website](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html)

input

> 0x0000000000000000003218a50000000000000000000000000000000000000000

output

> 4798269179035823348880781507454323228379569035237392384

I'm using mac

Comment: `python -c "print(0x0000000000000000003218a50000000000000000000000000000000000000000)"` and `ruby -e 'puts 0x0000000000000000003218a50000000000000000000000000000000000000000'` work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **bc**. Note letters should be in upper case. You can use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51983/how-to-uppercase-the-command-line-argument) answer to convert.

```
 echo "obase=10; ibase=16; 0000000000000000003218A50000000000000000000000000000000000000000" |bc
```

Comment: if Hash is lowercase
`echo "obase=10; ibase=16; -u; $(echo 0000000000000000003218a50000000000000000000000000000000000000000 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')" |bc | sed -n 2p`